# Как изменить директорию сохранения файла в Android Studio?

Tags: android

Есть код, где я беру ссылку и скачиваю музыку со своего сайта. Но не могу найти этот файл в папке загрузки. Но могу открыть этот mp3 файл в приложении загрузки.
Хочу знать, как можно сразу же сохранить музыкальный файл в папке загрузки.
А вот и сам код:

```
    web.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {
        public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent,
                                    String contentDisposition, String mimetype,
                                    long contentLength) {
            //Скачиваем выбранный файл
            dowloandManager = (DownloadManager)getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
            Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
            DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(uri);
            request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
            long reference = dowloandManager.enqueue(request);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Если файл открывается - значит он уже сохранён. Но не на всех аппаратах в папку "Download", может быть и другая, например "MyFavorite". Плюс к тому это может быть папка во встроенной памяти, а может не съёмной SD-карте.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь следующим кодом:

```
public void file_download(String uRl) {
    File direct = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            + "/dhaval_files");

    if (!direct.exists()) {
        direct.mkdirs();
    }

    DownloadManager mgr = (DownloadManager) this.getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);

    Uri downloadUri = Uri.parse(uRl);
    DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(
            downloadUri);

    request.setAllowedNetworkTypes(
            DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI
                    | DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_MOBILE)
            .setAllowedOverRoaming(false).setTitle("Demo")
            .setDescription("Something useful. No, really.")
            .setDestinationInExternalPublicDir("/dhaval_files", "test.jpg");

    mgr.enqueue(request);

}
```

И не забывайте предоставлять права на запись.